# Magento: load customer group by name

Tags: magento

How to load customer group by name in magento? I have tried this:

`$targetGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupName, 'name');`

but it throws a sql exception that column customer_group.name does not exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$targetGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group');
$targetGroup->load($groupName, 'customer_group_code');
```

Ref. `customer_group` table.

Comment: Thank you. That was fast and helpful.